# Python:Scrapy image download how to use custom filename

Tags: python, scrapy

- Scrapy:0.22.2
- Python:2.7.6
- OS:windows7 64

**Note：image_key is depressed in scrapy 0.22.2**

For my scrapy project I'm currently using the ImagesPipeline. The downloaded images are stored with a SHA1 hash of their URLs as the file names.

How can I store the files using my own custom file names instead?

Comment: yes,but my scrapy version is higher

Comment: There are three different solutions in the duplicate question, of which only one uses `image_key`. Please try the other two answers and then update the question to include any error messages or problems that occur.